# Approximate function with genetic algorithm

Tags: algorithm, function, approximation

Are there modules in python to approximate a given function(a) with a genetic algorithm to receive a function(b) which produces the same or similar outputs with the same inputs? Why approximate? The workings of function(a) are not known. So basically what the algorithm should do is minimizing the deviation from sample values produced by function(a) and mutating function(b). Any ideas?

Example:

```
1.Iteration:
f(a):  0 -> 5, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 7
f(bi): 0 -> 4, 1 -> 6, 2 -> 3
devi:       1       3       4
sum(devi):  8
...
f(bn): 0 -> 3, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 1
devn:       2       1       4
sum(devn):  7   ------------> 'fitter function - use for mutation'

mutate f(b):

2.Iteration:
f(a):  0 -> 5, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 7, ...
f(bi): 0 -> 5, 1 -> 6, 2 -> 3, ...
devi:       0       3       4
...
```

Comment: Are you sure about the genetic algorithm part? There is a number of good non-genetic function approximation algorithms. It would be best if you stated your problem constraints more explicitely (What kind of function should approximate the input function?).

Comment: No any approximation function would do I guess.

Comment: Then a polynomial of degree N (with N being the number of points in a) would suffice. Have numpy solve your equation system (X * A = Y with A being the parameters, X_ij = "the i-th input to the power of j" and Y as output values), and you're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're lookin for is called **[Extrapolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrapolation)** .

The are alot of algorithms that do that, and they're just mathematical so they can be easily implemented.

If you want to create a function that will simulate the first one with in the same range of input, you can use **[Interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation)** which is kinda the same, but with better accuracy because of the limited range.